# generator-angular - You don't seem to have generator with the name angular installed

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

So I wanted to take a look at the latest generator, seeing as they use gulp now.

Anyhow, after updating everything twice, reinstalling node, deleting npm-cache and so on, when I do **yo angular** the following happens:

- The generator starts and asks me the usual questions (grunt/gulp, sass? etc)
- I can choose the angular modules I want (ng-animate, etc.)
- It begins to generate the app skeleton

Then it crashes (before running npm install / bower install apparently), with the not very helpful message

```
Error angular

You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular:common:C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-angular\app\index.js installed.
```

The directory is there (generator-angular). The sub-directory is there (generator-angular/common). The index.js exists. I have installed and updated the generator and all the dependencies like 5 times now.

Now, the strange thing is, I tried older versions of yo and also generator-angular and they all fail with the same error message, so it's very likely something on my end, but I can't figure it out.

I've found older threads of this issue here on StackOverflow but all were solved by updating or fixing the path. None of that helped me :(

Here is the **yo doctor** output

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ Global configuration file is valid
√ Node.js version
√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ npm version
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Everything looks all right!
```

Also I'm on Win10x64. Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue, Win7 SP1 64-bit

Comment: Open Issues [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1239)
[yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1580)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by @SBoudrias in version 0.15.1. Can you try `npm uninstall -g yo && npm install -g yo` ?

Comment: I've tried several times to uninstall and install and it's not working. At least in Windows it seems to be still there

Comment: strange. Worked for me on win7 with node 5.3.0

Comment: Well, I've tried many times and it finally worked after adding karma globally. It suppose it's not necessary but it didn't work until I installed it. Thanks